# Dockerfile don't start my app just after npx prisma migrate

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, prisma

I'm trying to deploy a NodeJS application with Docker-Compose. My application works with Prisma but I can't do an `npm start` right after the migration... After searching I don't see the problem since I don't run my commands with the shell but with arrays...

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY ./ .

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["npx", "prisma", "migrate", "deploy"]

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The only output I get is this one:

[image: output]

My scripts part of my package.json:

```json
 "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
```

Comment: A Docker container runs only one command; if you specify both `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`, [they are combined into a single command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) and that is the only thing the container does.  Making the `ENTRYPOINT` be a script that runs the migration and then `exec "$@"` to run the `CMD` might be a better approach.

Comment: So I must create a .sh script who contains the twice commands?